# Windows 10 and Hyper V functionality

Tags: windows-8, windows-10

I have Windows 8 Professional and use the Hyper V functionality.

Recently I signed up for Windows 10 and a thought struct me i.e. do we keep all the functionality of Windows 8.

More importantly:

Do we get Hyper V in Windows 10 if we have it already installed on Windows 8? Y/N

Or

Do we have to buy/upgrade to Windows 10 Professional to get the Hyper V functionality? Y/N

If I have to buy/upgrade to Professional for Windows 10 I wont be upgrading because I am 100% sure the new features wont be that great that I really feel the urge to upgrade.

Cheers

C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upgrade from Windows 8 Pro you'll get Windows 10 Pro and will still have Hyper-v.

See http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-faq